# I have Finale and I am having trouble

Tags: recording

I have a keyboard.  I can play back a song that I have scored out and it plays through the keyboard.  But I want to play the keyboard with a song that I want to see it score on the staff in the computer.  I do not understand why when I play and hit record on the Finale program that I do not see the notes I am playing showing up on the staff.  I did it before but I am setting it up again this time and not it will not do it.  Help.

Comment: The version of Finale you are using and a step-by-step description of what you are doing, if possible with screenshot, might help.

Comment: The Finale company has a user support forum. You should post your questions there. There are many experts there that could help you. http://forum.makemusic.com

Comment: Have you read the Finale owners' manual? It contains a section on how to set it up for transcribing what you play.

Comment: Agreed with Wheat here, this question would be much better on the Finale forum.

Answer (score 0):

The makemusic forums are great but you may need to have some familiarity to start with before they make a lot of sense.  I would recommend the Finale: a Trailblazer Guide series by Mark Johnson.  Thorough and step-by-step.